# Write Radio Button Value to Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, radio-button

I have a Visualforce page on the Account Object that is meant to create a new Account record.  Part of my code uses  to create a selection of 3 radio buttons.  When the Visualforce page is saved and an Account record is created, I want the new Account record to be marked as the value of the radio button selected by the user.  I have 3 custom fields on the Account, each corresponds to one of the radio buttons.  Does anyone know how I can either get the value of the radio button to populate one of those 3 custom fields in my VF page, or how I can get the appropriate field populated on the Account based upon the radio button selection.  The code below accomplishes neither:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" tabStyle="Account" id="thePage">

<script>
    function TypeSelect(variable)
    {
        var choice = variable.value;
        if(choice == 'Amplify'){
document.getElementById({!$Component.thePage.theForm.checkBox.AmpVal}).checked = 'true';
        }
        else if(choice == 'Eng'){
document.getElementById({!$Component.thePage.theForm.checkBox.EngVal}).checked = 'true';
        }
        else{
document.getElementById({!$Component.thePage.theForm.checkBox.AgeVal}).checked = 'true';
        }
    }   
</script>

<style>
    input[type=radio] {margin-left: 100px;}
    .radioClass {margin-left: 25%;}
</style>
```

```
<apex:form id="theForm">

    <apex:actionRegion >
    <Table width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" columns="5">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="fieldLabel">
                <apex:selectRadio layout="lineDirection" styleClass="radioClass" onclick="TypeSelect(this);">
                <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Amp" itemValue="Amp"></apex:selectOption>
                <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Eng" itemValue="Eng"></apex:selectOption>
                <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Age" itemValue="Age"></apex:selectOption>
                </apex:selectRadio>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="thePage"/>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </Table><br/><br/>
    </div>


    <div id="checkBox">
        <apex:inputField styleClass="AmpVal" id="AmpVal" value="{!Account.Amp_Account__c}" />
        <apex:inputField styleClass="EngVal" id="EngVal" value="{!Account.Eng_Account__c}" />
        <apex:inputField styleClass="AgeVal" id="AgeVal" value="{!Account.Age_Account__c}" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be missing part of it (at the bottom). How are you saving it?

Comment: @Sebastian - I am just using the standard {!Save} function to save the data.  I added that into my code above.  The form itself is much larger, but the other sections were not relevant so I didn't want to waste space on this post.

Comment: I would suggest that you stick with your original question and edit it as necessary as you work through the solution instead of creating another question that asks the same thing. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/101697/660